# mysql insert bigint variable into tinyint type column

Tags: mysql, database

I've got tables users and devices with a user_id columns which are tinyint(3). 
I have to create a procedure which will add new user and update these tables with user_id. So I set the delimiter to // and make this:

```
create procedure add_user (in pr_name varchar(15), in pr_surname varchar(15), in pr_address varchar(15), in pr_pesel float(11,0), in pr_tel int (9), in pr_package_id tinyint(3) unsigned, in pr_mac varchar(17), in pr_model varchar(15), in pr_ip int(10) unsigned) 

begin 
    set @date = curdate(); 
    insert into users values (null, pr_name, pr_surname, pr_address, pr_pesel, pr_tel, pr_package_id);
    set @id = last_insert_id()
    insert into devices (pr_mac, pr_ip, @id, pr_model, @date); 
end;//
```

I want to take last added `user_id` from `users` (which is first column in users and is also auto-increment) and put it into `user_id` in `devices` table. Mysql returns an syntax error near `'null, @id, pr_model, @date); end'`.
I think it's because `last_insert_id()` function returns `bigint unsigned`.
Please help me with this.

Comment: You don't get a syntax error from data type mismatches, they're just based on syntax.

Comment: I don't see `null, @id, pr_model, @date` anywhere in the procedure. The only syntax error I see is the missing `;` at the end of the `set @id` line.

Comment: If the userId is an auto increment column you need not pass null just pass in the other values

Comment: @ArunGopinathan But then you have to list all the column names, so you can leave out the `user_id` column.

Comment: @Barmar yes thats right. may be we will see if he tries the missing ; you suggested

Comment: Note: 15 characters for names is ridiculously short. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default for string-like fields and only restrict them if you have a very compelling reason. Likewise, using `INT` for telephone numbers is a bad idea. `+1-555-555-5555x2390` is a valid telephone number.

Comment: It's also *really* odd to see a floating point number used when it's not allowed to have any decimal precision.